# Pipeline design question when using lettuce for Redis

Tags: redis, lettuce

I'm using pipeline with lettuce, and I have a design question. When trying send a block of commands to redis using the 'sendBlock' method below, I'm thinking about 2 options:

(1) Having one instance of the connection already established in the class, and reuse it:

```
private void sendBlock()
{   
   this.conn.setAutoFlushCommands(false);
   (...)
   this.conn.flushCommands();
}
```

(2) Every time I send a block of commands get a connection from redis, perform the action and close it.

```
private void sendBlock()
{
   StatefulRedisModulesConnection<String, String> conn = RedisClusterImpl.connect();
   conn.setAutoFlushCommands(false);
   (...)
   conn.flushCommands();
   conn.close();
}
```

Since established connections seem to be shared between all threads in lettuce, I'm not sure if point 1 is correct. If not, I have to go to point 2. And in this case I don't know how costly is to obtain a connection from Redis, so I'm wondering if I need to use pooling (thing that is not recommended in the lettuce docs). In our use case the 'sendBlock' method can be simultaneously called hundreds of times, so it's intensively used by a lot of different threads.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Joan.

Answer (score 0):

Lettuce connections are thread-safe and can be shared if you don't use Redis-blocking commands (ex. BLPOP) and transactions.

Those should be performed on separate connections, as the transaction will apply to the entire connection, and blocking operations will block the connection until they're complete.

Whether or not you should share a manually-flushed connection depends only on the number of operations you perform between flushes. Ex. if each block is 10k commands, and you have 10 threads, you could queue 100k to send at once where you expected 10k. Whether or not this matters will depend on your application, and you should check the performance of your individual case.

If each block is not sending many commands you may not even need to flush manually as Lettuce pipelines with auto-flush enabled (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75197859/5699459)).